# How to fix "failed to set referrer policy: The value ' ' is not one of..."?

Tags: 404-error, plugin-w3-total-cache

So I am not sure where to start with this problem. Client is unable to see this page: https://www.godental365.com/patient-reviews/

It does not seem to load for them or a few people in my office. I believe it might have something to do with the W3 Total Cache plugin.

I am viewing the site in Chrome on a Mac (not sure what browser config client is using). When I inspect the page in console I get the "Failed to set referrer policy" error a bunch of times.

So first thing I did was uncheck Referrer policy in the W3 plugin Brower Cache settings. That was a suggestion I saw from doing some searching. Didn't seem to help but I get a new error now. Now the console just gives me a bunch of 404 errors pointing to this: https://www.godental365.com/patient-reviews/%3Cscript%20type=

Im not sure what this is or how to fix it. Any direction would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 4):

**Chris** did you try the solution from the [WordPress Forum](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/failed-to-set-referrer-policy-error/)?

According to some users, this can solve the problem. Go into your **.htaccess** file and change the following:

> Header set Referrer-Policy ""

to

> Header set Referrer-Policy "origin"

Comment: It worked in my case for I am developing in localhost, it is related to Referrer-Policy in the server settings which may due to my localhost not setting '' as referrer. During Production, '' nothing is not a problem which might be due to my server is setting '' as referrer.

Comment: For other referrer values, please read on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy

Answer (score 3):

If you use **W3 Total Cache** verify this solution: [WordPress Failed to Set Referrer Policy Response Headers – W3 Total Cache](https://web.archive.org/web/20180827171724/https://623lafayette.com/2018/05/02/wordpress-failed-to-set-referrer-policy/)

Comment: Thanks, this solutions is more comprehensive and right practice to resolve.